# Adding or subtracting functions results in none type error

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm working on a class assignment where we have to use a given function and find the difference between it and the math.sqrt module. Anytime I try to add or subtract any functions (I used different examples to try and figure out the issue on my own) I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' (I am using PythonAnywhere).

This is what I am working on:

```
    import math
    def my_sqrt(a):
        x = a
        while True:
            print(x)
            y = (x + a/x) / 2
            if y == x:
                break
            x = y
    def test_sqrt(a):
        b = my_sqrt(a)
        c = math.sqrt(a)
        d = abs(b-c)
        print(d)
```

Comment: Your functions do not `return` anything. What do you expect to happen to `b` when you do `b = my_sqrt(a)`, and how does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something in `my_sqrt` function. It's returning `None` currently.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It was meant to be returning 'x' and I just missed that part of the instructions! Thank you!